# Change org-mode table style just for LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, latex

I am trying to customize the style of my org-mode tables when exported to Latex. I need to change their font face, their font size, the background color of the header and the background color of every other rows.

I see lots of discussions on how to do these things in pure LaTeX, using (or not) additional packages like pgfplotstable. But I would like to keep my document as 'org-mode' style as possible (for readability and because I also export in HTML).

There are ways to specify basic options via attribute, but it won't take me far enough: http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html#LaTeX-specific-attributes

Is there a way to specify in an org-mode document that tables should use a particular format/structure (maybe in an external .sty) when exporting to LaTeX without messing the basic org-mode style table for other exports?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm doing mainly tables with the latex packages `#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{booktabs}`, `\usepackage{xcolor}`, `\usepackage{colortbl}` and `\usepackage{siunitx}`.  Together with export attributes.  For example:

`#+LATEX: \definecolor{contiYellow}{RGB}{255,165,0}
 #+LATEX: \rowcolors[]{2}{contiYellow!5}{contiYellow!20}
 #+ATTR_LATEX: :align rS
| *Type*                                     | *Stiffness* in N/mm |
|--------------------------------------------+---------------------|
| Two bearings SKF in radial dir. (supplier) |              167800 |
| Measurement bearings + rotor + device      |                8398 |
| Measurement device                         |               14753 |
| Calculation rotor + bearings               |               19500 |
|--------------------------------------------+---------------------|
| Sim. Rotor + "bearings" (package solid)    |               50900 |
| Sim. Rotor + "joints" (package solid)      |               33320 |
| Sim. Shaft + "bearings" (without package)  |               12000 |
| Sim. Shaft + "bearings" 10 mm              |               20030 |
 #+TBLFM: @2$2=2*8.39e4`

gives me

[image]

Comment: cannot reproduce your output. Do you need anything else to run this? In particular latex complains about  `\rowcolors[]{2}{contiYellow!5}{contiYellow!20}`, undefined control sequence. I have installed the 3 above packages.

Comment: @DJJ: I'm sorry I forgot the give you right packages, I updated the answer.

Comment: Many thanks. But I still cannot reproduce the output. I get the same error. I guess the clue might be `:align rS`. I don't know what the S stands for. When using the `colortable` package one need to input ` \rowcolors[`, on each row. Have you found a way of looping through the rows?

Comment: This `S` is for aligning numbers in a nicely way, for testing purposes you might use `l` or so.  You might need `\usepackage{siunitx}` for it

Comment: Thanks. I think I have found the culprit. With `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` it works as expected. Many thanks again

Comment: @DJJ: You're very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how much modification of the exported LaTeX you need, you might be able to use a filter, e.g. if all you need to do is wrap the latex in some additional LaTeX: http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/filter-markup.html

If the changes are more complex, it sounds like you need a custom exporter, eg http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html where you could define a function that generates the latex code you want for a table.